# APPCMD exception bubbles up on Sitecore 10 CM container start, why?

Tags: iis, docker-compose, dockerfile, sitecore

The [container I'm baking](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/build-sitecore-solutions.html) constantly fails:

```
Service 'w3svc' has been stopped

APPCMD failed with error code 4312

Failed to update IIS configuration
[2021-02-15T21:35:11.000Z][LOGMONITOR] INFO: Entrypoint processs exit code: -2147467259
```

It is built out of [Sitecore 10 image](https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-images/blob/master/build/windows/tests/10.0.x/sitecore-xm1/docker-compose.yml) with solution files on top:

```
# escape=`
# Clean Sitecote 10 image
ARG RUNTIME_IMAGE
# Image with custom code
ARG ASSETS_IMAGE

ARG TOOLING_IMAGE

FROM ${ASSETS_IMAGE} AS assets 
FROM ${TOOLING_IMAGE} as tooling
FROM ${RUNTIME_IMAGE} AS runtime
ARG TRANSFORM

ARG CONFIGURATION=Release

WORKDIR C:/inetpub/wwwroot

COPY --from=assets "c:\out\Website\" .
COPY  Invoke-XdtTransform.ps1 .

COPY --from=tooling \tools\ \tools\
```

I cannot even start it and inspect to investigate deeper so all I have is the error message from [AppCmd.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe)

How to figure out why it dies?

Thanks.